# Installation of El Capitan within VM is very slow

Tags: virtualbox, osx-elcapitan

I created a bootable ISO image by following guide of [osx-vm-templates](https://github.com/timsutton/osx-vm-templates). And then I create a new VM and configured it to boot from the ISO image in VirtualBox, I get a workable OSX VM at the end.

But the installation process takes about 2 hours to complete, why?

Answer (score 0):

The box I'm using for creating VM runs **Server.app**, the installation process now cause about **40 minutes** after I removed **Server.app**.